# System.InvalidOperationException, Object in use elsewhere

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I am getting InvalidOperationException at random times.

```
public void abStart()
{ 
    try
    {
        AB ab = new AB(wb.getCookies(), side);
        Application.Run(ab); //this is where the exception is thrown
    }
    catch {  }
}
```

This method is executed on a different thread like this:

```
if (abON[0] == null || !abON[0].IsAlive)
{
    abON[0] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abStart));
    abON[0].SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    abON[0].Start();
}
```

Comment: Normal use would be to call Application.Run once to get the windows message pump going. Why do you need Application.Run to be called multiple times? What do you try to achieve?

Comment: I thought that because it is a windows form (not just a class w/o ui) i am calling I need to use Application.Run ?

Comment: I'm not saying it is impossible but if you have one application message pump going you can can show new forms by creating one and call show on it: `var frm = new MyForm(); frm.Show();`

Comment: It is the kind of exception you get when you try to use a Bitmap on two threads at the same time.  You've created plenty of opportunities for this to happen of course.  You need to look at the Call Stack window to have a guess at where this exception occurs, it typically happens inside .NET Framework code that you don't have source code for.  Like a control's OnPaint() method.  Creating UI on more than one thread is an advanced programming technique with many nasty pitfalls and very few practical uses.

Answer (score 0):

This should help

```
public void abStart()
    {
        try
        {
            AB ab = new AB(wb.getCookies(), side);
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
            Application.Run(ab); //this is where the exception is thrown
            });
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

And this code improve to this:

```
        try
        {
            this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate
            {
                // handles the code on its own thread
                if (abON[0] == null || !abON[0].IsAlive)
                {
                    abON[0] = new Thread(new ThreadStart(abStart));
                    abON[0].SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
                    abON[0].Start();
                }
            });
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("" + ex);
        }
```

Reason is that you are facing cross-threading